# file upload on bluemix in nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm currently developing a node.js bluemix application, which offers an api image/file upload, which then processes the images with the mongodb  Service. Locally, this service works perfectly. Unfortunately, the service can't access the uploaded files on bluemix? - How to fix this? Thank you in advance

```
require('rootpath')();
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var session = require('express-session');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var expressJwt = require('express-jwt');
var config = require('config.json');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var helmet = require('helmet');
var cors = require('cors');
var md5 = require('md5');
var sha1 = require('js-sha1');
var sha256 = require('js-sha256');
var crypto = require('crypto');
var path = require('path');
var multer = require('multer');

var mkdirp = require('mkdirp');




var storage = multer.diskStorage({

    destination: function(req, file, cb) {
        var dir = './uploads/' + req.query.projectId + '/' + req.query.milestoneId + '/';
        mkdirp(dir, function(err) {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err);
            }
            // move cb to here
            cb(null, dir);
        });

        console.log("Upload: saved to " + dir + file.originalname);
    },
    filename: function(req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, file.originalname);
    }

})



var upload = multer({ storage: storage })



var genRandomString = function(length) {
    return crypto.randomBytes(Math.ceil(length / 2))
        .toString('hex') /** convert to hexadecimal format */
        .slice(0, length); /** return required number of characters */
};
var sha512 = function(password, salt) {
    var hash = crypto.createHmac('sha512', salt); /** Hashing algorithm sha512 */
    hash.update(password);
    var value = hash.digest('hex');
    return {
        salt: salt,
        passwordHash: value
    };
};

function saltHashPassword(userpassword) {
    var salt = genRandomString(16); /** Gives us salt of length 16 */
    var passwordData = sha512(userpassword, salt);
    console.log('UserPassword = ' + userpassword);
    console.log('Passwordhash = ' + passwordData.passwordHash);
    console.log('nSalt = ' + passwordData.salt);
}

//saltHashPassword('MYPASSWORD');
//saltHashPassword('MYPASSWORD');

app.use(cors());
app.use(helmet());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(session({ secret: config.secret, resave: false, saveUninitialized: true }));

// use JWT auth to secure the api
app.use('/api', expressJwt({ secret: config.secret }).unless({ path: ['/api/users/authenticate', '/api/users/register'] }));

// routes

app.use('/api/fileuploads', require('./controllers/api/svr.fileupload.controller'));
app.use('/api/session', require('./controllers/api/svr.session.controller'));
app.use('/api/uploadImage', require('./controllers/api/svr.imageUpload.controller'));


app.use('/js', express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js')); // redirect bootstrap JS
app.use('/js', express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules/jquery/dist')); // redirect JS jQuery
app.use('/css', express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css')); // redirect CSS bootstrap
app.use('/img', express.static(__dirname + '/views'));
app.use('/img/project', express.static(__dirname + '/images'));
app.use('/file/project', express.static(__dirname + '/files'));
app.use('/uploadDoc', express.static(__dirname + '/uploads'));
app.use('/uploadImage', express.static(__dirname + '/images'));


app.post('/savedata', upload.single('file'), function(req, res, next) {
    console.log('Upload Successful req.file = ', req);
    console.log('Upload Successful req.body = ', req.body);

    var hash1 = md5(req.file);

    console.log('md5=', hash1);
    saltHashPassword(hash1);

    return res.send(hash1);
});




// make '/app' default route
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    return res.redirect('/app');
});

// start server
var server = app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, function() {
    console.log('Server listening at http://' + server.address().address + ':' + server.address().port);
});
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the "edit" link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

Comment: Point being "does not work" **always** has some sort of feedback. So it things are not working, then there will be an error or such. You also seem to believe you dumped your entire listing on us. This is not true. 9/10 your "does not work" will be because you failed to change your database connection details or other differing details for the deployment. None of that is specified here at all. And frankly if your main listing lacks a database connection and you are using one, then you actually have much bigger problems with your code.